# autocorrectType is not working on iOS 13 using swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, ios13, autocorrect

I know this is quiet simple and straight forward to disable autocorrection on iPhone and it worlds pretty much fine, but until now. Surprisingly, suggestion bar appear for text field even I have disabled it from storyboard and even programmatically.

```
self.textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Done that in sotoryboard as well.

[image]

But it does appear on iOS 13, not on previous versions and simulator.

[image]

There are many answers already for this one but none is working on iOS 13 so no need to mark the question as duplicate.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution for this? It's funny I'm facing the same issue. Have the sh*t disabled everywhere in a code and in a xib file. And despite all of that it's still correcting all input using some suggestions

Comment: Have the same issue, without using Storyboards... Pretty annoying when entering emails.

Comment: Have the same issue, can't solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

If you are using a Storyboard you can disable autocorrection on the attributes inspector (the down arrow icon) under the Text input traits. See the image below for details.

[image]

Comment: It still corrects all input no matter what. Topic starter has explained that he have all this disabled